# Some propreties about $ \mathfrak{Coh}_X $ and $ \mathfrak{QCoh}_X $.

Tags: category-theory, vector-bundles, abelian-categories, coherent-sheaves, quasicoherent-sheaves

I would like to know :

- why is the category $ \mathfrak{Coh}_X $ of coherent scheaves the smallest abelian category containing line bundles ?
- Why is the category $ \mathfrak{QCoh}_X $ of quasi coherent scheaves the smallest abelian category containing locally free scheaves ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This more-or-less amounts to the observation that quasicoherent (resp. coherent) sheaves arise as the cokernels of locally free sheaves (resp. locally free sheaves of finite rank).